# fetching values from all textboxes in c# in one go?

Tags: c#, textbox

I want to capture all the textboxes values  on button click in string without explicitly writing each of this line for each textbox in c# like

```
string atv1 = TextBox1.Text;
string atv2 = TextBox2.Text;
```

It should find all textboxes and make a string of it (join) .

can anyone help out !!

(window form when making some asp.net website (c#))

Answer (score 2):

concise way :

```
String.Join(",",Form.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Select(c => c.Text))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `StringBuilder` to "join" (most software types use the term concatenate) the strings.  To get all the TextBoxes you can select any control on the form that is a text box.  Simple solution is

```
var s = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var textbox in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
   s.AppendLine(textbox.Text)
}

Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
```

However, a `TextBox` can be inside of a `Control` on the `Form`.  So to handle this case you need recursion.  I'll leave you to search StackOverflow to figure out how to do this.

Comment: string.Join("", this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Select(tb => tb.Text))

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
  if (c is TextBox)
  {
     var txt = (TextBox)c;
     //Do Something
  }
}
```

Comment: have you understand what the user wants? doesn't seem correct answer

Comment: hi @riddle-- i am wanting to concatenate all the textboxes values in a string . It should fetch values from all textboxes on button click. We could do like string v1=textbox1.text , but i dont want to do it manually for each textbox.

Comment: It was half an answer, I demonstrated how to get all the textboxes on a form, under the assumption that "this" is in the form context.

Answer (score 0):

More elegant way:

```
var objTextboxValues = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Select(obj => obj.Text).ToList();
var varJoinedText = String.Join(", ", objTextboxValues);
```

Original Answer:

```
var varAllTextBoxValues = "";

foreach (Control objControl in this.Controls)
    if (objControl is TextBox)
        varAllTextBoxValues += ((TextBox)objControl).Text;
    }

MessageBox.Show(varAllTextBoxValues);
```

Comment: @vitox- Label3.Text =varJoinedText;                                                                    No error but ; Does not show me anything on label. Label also vanishes.

Comment: That's really odd, because I just tested and it worked perfectly. Are you using a Windows Form right!? Did you put this code inside the click event of your button, and this button resides in the same form that the textboxes are also, right!?